# Pandas cut function gives fewer categories than desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks likes this

```
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
0    0.3   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.7   0.5
1    0.7   0.6   0.4   0.6   0.7   1.0
2    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3    0.1   0.9   0.5   0.7   0.7   0.9
4    0.3   2.3   0.4   2.0   1.9   1.9
5    4.0   1.2   0.6   1.2   2.6   3.1
6    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7    0.0   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2
8    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
9    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
10   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1
11   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1
12   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

I want to create 4 bins (strictly 4 bins) for every column so i apply the `pandas` `cut` function in each column separately. So I do

```
import pandas as pd
qt = so.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x,4))
```

Then if I do

```
qt.var1.unique()
```

I get

```
[(-0.004, 1.0], (3.0, 4.0]]
Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(-0.004, 1.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]
```

Which has only 2 categories.

Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: It's because 2 of your bins have no values ie, there are no values in the range `(1, 3]`... instead of `unique` try `qt['var1'].cat.categories`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `var1` you split the data in equal-width bins in the range of `var1`. So you have a range from `0` to `4` so you get the intervals:

`Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.004, 1.0] < (1.0, 2.0] < (2.0, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]`

`unique` only shows 2, because there are only values in 2 of the 4 intervals.

Explanation for `-0.004`:

> The range of x is extended by .1% on each side to include the minimum and maximum values of x.

Comment: the equally sized bins creates the problem. I see it now. Otherwise it would make sense to me to group them something like: `[(-0.004, 0.1) < [0.1, 0.3] < [0.7, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) specify that the bins have the same width:

> Defines the number of equal-width bins in the range of x...

In your case, you can not create 4 equal bins to fit your data in. Here an example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12)
>>> print(len(pd.cut(a, 4).unique()))
4

>>> b = np.array([1,2,3, 10, 20])
>>> print(len(pd.cut(b, 4).unique()))
3
```

As you can see, in the latter case only 4 bins are created, but only 3 are used

Answer (score 1):

There's literally no way to categorize into 4 bins an array like this: `[5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0]`. The same happens to you. As mentioned earlier, you **can** create 4 bins, but it doesn't mean, that all of them will be used:

```
>>> qt = df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x,4))
>>> qt.var1.unique()
[(-0.004, 1.0], (3.0, 4.0]]
Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(-0.004, 1.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]

>>> qt.var1.value_counts()
(-0.004, 1.0]    13
(3.0, 4.0]        1
(2.0, 3.0]        0
(1.0, 2.0]        0
Name: var1, dtype: int64
```

It worth saying that there are 2 types of binning: equal-width and equal-height. `pd.cut` is for equal-width - it creates `n` bins with the *~same* width. For same-height you can use `pd.qcut` that uses quantiles. Also, it doesn't mean that you'll get stricktly `n` bins, because quantiles may be the same.

```
>>> qt = df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 4, duplicates='drop'))
>>> qt.var1.unique()
[(0.25, 4.0], (-0.001, 0.05], (0.05, 0.25]]
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 0.05] < (0.05, 0.25] < (0.25, 4.0]]
>>> qt.var1.value_counts()
(-0.001, 0.05]    7
(0.25, 4.0]       4
(0.05, 0.25]      3
Name: var1, dtype: int64
```